# variables in sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

how can i use a variable in sequence diagram.. while sequence diagram show object calling in timelines...

Comment: any one have reply for this...

Answer (score 5):

You can use formal/actual parameters on the messages, and action-boxes on a particular lifeline, filled with your own specification language, e.g. Java-style assignments. The example below is for Message Sequence Charts, but works roughly the same for UML sequence diagrams, I just couldn't find a screenshot in a hurry:[image]